# Watir-Webdriver: I want to click on the last button with the same class or value

Tags: ruby, element, watir-webdriver

I am having trouble having my script work and finding a suitable solution.

The issue I am facing is I cannot get my code to go to the last button on the page and click on it. It seems like a trivial issue, but I am well and truly stumped. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my code of what I have tried albeit with no success

`@browser.button.last(:value => 'Unlock').click` or `@browser.button(:class => 'btn btn-danger').last.click`

The error I keep getting is

> undefined method 'last'

The reason why I cannot use an index in my code is because the number of buttons on the web page are not constant as the number of buttons on display can randomly increase or decrease. Hence my predicament.

Comment: You're missing an 's'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`buttons`](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Container#buttons-instance_method) method to map all the buttons on the page and then click use the `last` method on the collection.  For example:

```
buttons = b.buttons(:class => "class_name_here")
buttons.last.click
```

Comment: The same in one line: `browser.buttons(:class => "class_name_here").last.click`

Comment: Thanks guys, can't believe I missed that. Too much over thinking. Much appreciated